# SQL pivot query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
name----address----type----value
 a      finland    color    120
 a      finland    wage     500
```

what i want is to show `color` and `wage` values as columns:

```
name----address----color----wage
 a      finland     120     500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT name, address, type, value
        FROM   table)
PIVOT  (SUM(value)  FOR (type) IN ('color', 'wage'));
```

Comment: I had to put single quotes around 'color' and 'wage', otherwise it produces a "non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values" error.